# In a form, how do I display field data from another table as text without a combobox?

Tags: ms-access

tblStaff lists staff and tblAssign lists staff assignments. They are linked through StaffID, which is tblStaff's primary key and tblAssign's foreign key.

I have created formAssign based on tblAssign. In formAssign, StaffID is set through a combo box where the tblStaff's StaffName is displayed and selcted (created with combo box wizard). However, I also want to display some other fields in formAssign from tblStaff that would vary based on StaffID (eg. StaffPaygrade), but I don't want this data to display in a combo box. I want it just to appear as text.

The closest thing I can come up with is to make a combo box displaying StaffPaygrade linked through StaffID and then lock it, but this looks pretty bad.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: `AfterUpdate` of the combobox, retrieve the records using a recordset, iterate through the record set and assign to a text box.

Comment: You can use an unbound textbox with a `=DLookup('ShowThisColumn','tblAssign','StaffID = ' & Me!StaffIdComboBox)` as source

Comment: On the other hand, the cheapest way would be to show them in the first combobox (if you do't mind). You can just concatenate fields from the recordsource of the combobox and show them as the display column, e.g. `SELECT id, id & " - " lastname & ", " & firstname FROM mySource` with bound column 1 and column 1's width 0.